# How to create a "suspension" for fast moving objects?

Tags: game-engine, objects, physics

I have searched this for long and have found nothing about.

I'm trying to make a racing game like Mario Kart, but when my character reaches a certain speed, hes bounces up, like hopping, at any slight change of the ground geometry. Even at invisible edges of completely flat planes with no imperfection.

I know the *Object Type Character* fixes that with "step height" option, but I cannot use the "servo control"  actuator on it, which is crucial.

How to add a tolerance to this small imperfections with the "dynamic object"?

Unfortunately I'm not a programmer, I am an Artist, and wondering how far I can get using the logic editor, and simple scrips.

Ill leave my project here, so you can see for yourself. Note that the details of the map such as the edges of the platforms are set to "no collision", so this is not the problem.

[image]

- <kbd>X</kbd> Accel
- <kbd>Z</kbd> Brake
- <kbd>C</kbd> Shoot Item
- <kbd>A</kbd> Hop / Drift
- <kbd>Q</kbd>, <kbd>E</kbd> Side Step
- <kbd>Arrows</kbd> - Direction

Comment: Your file is not easily downloadable, please use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com and upload a simplifyed version of the file with minimal data to illustrate the problem

Answer (score 1):

This is not too surprising behaviour, and the solution is to not have things rubbing at high speed. In real life, your car would grind the bottom off completely. 
Probably the most useful solution is to suggest using [BGE's vehicle wrapper](http://www.tutorialsforblender3d.com/Game_Engine/Vehicle/Vehicle_2.html).

Comment: ohh. O Will try ir. it seem that I Will have to make a lot of motion actuactor modification using this. if it work I choose you answer.

Comment: unfortunately that ain't gonna work for me. that system use a rigid bodies, are not compatible with the systems that I have made for dinamic body, also rigid bodies flip around with realistic physics, that's not the goal for my Kart like game. The part that interested me is the suspension, but it needs the complex system of tires and stuff attached, I can't simply use on my player. But now a have an direction. my player needs a simple suspension, a tolerance to de slight variations on ground. any idea how do achieve this with dynamic body?